# Use of undeclared type or module in a Rust test but I imported it

Tags: module, rust

I have a crate with a structure like so:

```
pub mod components {
    pub mod ch {
        pub struct CH {
            // struct definition
        }

        impl CH {
            pub fn new() -> CH {
                CH {}
            }
        }
    }
}

use components::ch::CH;

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

    #[test]
    fn ch_test() {
        let test_ch = CH::new();
    }
}
```

When I run the tests, I get an error:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `CH`
  --> src/lib.rs:22:23
   |
22 |         let test_ch = CH::new();
   |                       ^^ use of undeclared type or module `CH`
```

I also get a warning stating that my import is unused:

```
warning: unused import: `components::ch::CH`
  --> src/lib.rs:15:5
   |
15 | use components::ch::CH;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: #[warn(unused_imports)] on by default
```

This tells me that somehow my module structure isn't identifying my code correctly. I checked [Rust by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/mod/split.html) and I can't see how my code differs. Where is my file structure not connected properly?

Comment: I think you have to move the `use` into `mod tests`. Not sure though.

Comment: @Ry- that worked